# Algebra; Functions & Graphs

Tags: functions

Given:
[image]

Why is -2 non-inclusive?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The derivative of the function (the slope) is 0 at x = -2.

The definition of an increasing function requires that the slope be strictly positive. :)

Comment: I presume you mean *strictly* increasing and are talking about continuously differentiable functions.  Then if the slope is positive, it's true that $f$ is strictly increasing, but not the converse; consider $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Do you mind to explain my error?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I mean this *answer* is incorrect - yours is the correct one!  I even upvoted it!

Comment: @MarkMcClure thanks for clarification.

Comment: I'm sorry now I am confused.  The definition of increasing requires that $f'(x) > 0$.  Here $x=-2$ is a critical point, therefore the function cannot be increasing there.

Comment: Furthermore, the way the question is phrased suggests that $(-\infty, -2]$ was another possible answer but nonetheless marked incorrectly.  @MarkMcClure, perhaps I am misunderstanding something fundamental but I do not see an error here.

Comment: @incompleteness By *definition*, a function $f$ defined on an interval $I$ is strictly increasing on $I$ if $f(x)<f(y)$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are numbers in $I$ with $x<y$. This makes no mention of the derivative at all. It is a *theorem* that *if* $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $I$ with $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$, then $f$ is increasing on $I$. This is a sufficient condition, not a necessary condition.

Comment: I see- yes, of course that makes perfect sense. Strangely when I looked back to my Calculus notes, "increasing" had been defined the same way I had previously, however, when I check my Analysis notes this had been corrected.  Thank you and sorry for the stupid error on my part!

Answer (score 1):

The function is strictly increasing on any interval $J\subset(-\infty,-2]$, so the suggested answer is true since $(-\infty,-2)\subset(-\infty,-2]$.

Comment: This is correct.